# GEE Bulk download modis time series clipped by given ROI

Tags: libgee

I need to bulk download the modis LST time-series clipped by the given ROI in my local folder, this code running successfully, but when I run exported images in my tasks, there is an error didn't download images.
**error: Can't transform (23807.0,20016.0) (Error code: 3)**

```
    var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
    var table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-xrpt/assets/studyarea");
    Map.addLayer(table);
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1').select('LST_Day_1km')
    var dataset_filter = dataset.filterDate('2019-09-01','2020-01-10')
                                //.map(function(image){return image.clip(table)})
                               .limit(2);
    function clp(img) {
      return img.clip(table)

}

var clippeddataset = dataset_filter.map(clp)
                            
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(clippeddataset, 'Folder', 
                {scale: 1000, 
                 region: table.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'})
```